# How can I replace lumped capacitor and inductor with microstrip line?

Tags: capacitor, switches, inductor, microstrip, lumped

[image]

**This is a spst switch working on 2.4 GHz. I want to replace the inductor and capacitors with microstrip line. What is the easy way to do that?**

Comment: How wide a band around 2.4 GHz are you using? Which inductors and which capacitors do you want to replace?

Comment: Its a switch. When it is on it will pass frequencies from 2.2 to 2.6 Ghz. I want to replace all the capacitors and inductors of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

2.4 GHz is a fairly low frequency when it comes to trying to make useful L or C-equivalents with microstrip structures.

But instead of trying to make direct equivalents, you could consider some other options that will achieve the required functionality.

- Instead of capacitors C19 and C20, you could make a directional coupler structure that blocks DC while passing your 2.4 GHz signal.
- Instead of L13, you can work out what length of shorted stub line produces a high impedance at its input at 2.4 GHz.
- You could do the same for L14, but you'll have to be careful how you terminate it.

You probably can't generate 220 nF of capacitance in a practical microstrip structure to replace C21. But you might be able to find a parallel combination of discrete capacitors that provides low impedance over your signal band, in order to terminate the stub line you're using to replace L14.